# jQueryUIのui-frontクラスの使い方

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

jQueryUI DialogのAPIには、かつて`zIndex`オプションがありましたが、現在はありません。
そこで、代替手段は無いのだろうかと調べた所、下記のページを見つけました。

http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/stacking-elements/

どうやら`ui-front`クラスを介して`z-index`の制御ができるようなことを書いてあると思うのですが、私は英語が苦手であるため、いまいち内容を理解できません。
このページでは、どのようなことが解説されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

目的が不明ですので概要だけ。たとえばfirefoxならば開発ツールのインスペクタなどでみるとわかりますが、jquery-uiでダイアログを作成すると、ダイアログの実体である以下のようなDOMがbody要素の一番最後に追加されます。

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" ...>
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" ...>
    ...略...
    </div>
</div>
```

最後に追加されるということは、z-indexは特別な指定がなくとも内部的に最大ですから、どの要素よりも上にレンダリングされます。また、ダイアログを生成した順で重なってレンダリングされることでしょう。これが通常の動作で、ふつうはこれで十分です。

しかしajaxなどでさらにbodyの最後尾に追加された要素が描画される場合、内部的にz-indexがダイアログよりも大きくなります。あるいは、明示的にCSSなどでz-indexが指定された要素があるばあい、その値がダイアログのz-indexより大きければ、もちろんダイアログが隠れてしまいます。

こういった状況を考慮して、ダイアログがいかなる状況でも手前にくるためには、事実上到達不可能な大きなz-indexを設定しておくことがひとつ挙げられ、これをするためのクラスとして`.ui-front`が用意されている、ということでしょう。

```
.ui-front { z-index: 99999999; /* めちゃでかい値 */ }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ht1foyo8/

```js
var d1 = $('#dialog1');
var d2 = $('#dialog2');
d1.dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});
d2.dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});

$('#open1').click(function() {
  d1.dialog('open');
});
$('#open2').click(function() {
  d2.dialog('open');
});
```

```css
#base {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 211, 0.4);
}

//.ui-front { z-index: 100000; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/jqueryui-editable/js/jqueryui-editable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/jqueryui-editable/css/jqueryui-editable.css">

<button id="open1">open 1</button>
<button id="open2">open 2</button>

<div id="dialog1" title="dialog first">sample</div>
<div id="dialog2" title="dialog second">example</div>

<div id="base">
  this<br /> is
  <br /> base
  <br /> element
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br />
</div>
```

こちらにサンプルを用意してみました。最初は`.ui-front`のCSSルールがコメントアウトされているので、ダイアログよりも上に要素が表示されますが、コメントを解除すればダイアログが上になるはずです。

> Note: When using ui-front, you must also set position to relative, absolute or fixed in order for the z-index to be applied.

注意としては、z-indexが有効となるために、対象要素の`position`CSSプロパティが`static`以外になっている必要がある、とありますが、少なくともdialogではabsoluteなので気にしないでいいでしょう。

以上、質問の趣旨に合っていない、あるいは私の理解がそもそも誤っていたら申し訳ありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。あくまで静的にCSSでz-indexを指定しておけるという目的のものに過ぎず、`ui-front`要素に対してJavaScriptで操作をすることで、ダイアログの表示順などを動的に操作することを目的としたものではない、という認識であっていますか？（できるとは思いますが、そのような使い方のために提供されているわけではない、と）

Comment: 解説ページの「The stacking technique」の項にある内容が読解できず、どんな使い方のために提供されているのかな、という疑問を持っています。techniqueとあるので、「こういう使い方できるよ」という内容なのかなと思ったのですが、そもそもそういう主旨ではない？

Comment: まず「The ui-front class is very basic. It just sets a static z-index value on the element.」という箇所ですが、「静的にCSSでz-indexを指定しておける」よ、とだけ言っています。また、「The stacking technique」の記述は、`appendTo`オプションを利用して、特定の要素にダイアログ等を追加するとき、`.ui-front`クラスの有無を判別して、`.ui-front`に設定されたz-indexの意図を反映できるように、DOMの追加のしかたが内部的に変わるよ、という内容と理解しております。私は過去の`zIndex`オプションは利用したことがないのですが、これを利用して「ダイアログの表示順などを動的に操作する」ことなどができたのでしょうか。そうであるなら、このクラスをquerySelectorAllなどで取得し、操作する方法に変更されたのでしょう（あまり利用されない、あるいはコードメンテナンスの事情など）。そうでなければ、単純にz-index関連の問題を修正するための手段だと思います。